# How to make non-modal MessageBox pop-ups for Unity project

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, messagebox

Gday,

I am currently doing a small Unity project where the game takes place on the desktop, we have a creature that communicates with the player. It is currently severely limited with how it acts/reacts due to the only way that I can figure out how to make popups in the windows system style is through the use of the MessageBox function which is Modal (it suspends the application from running until the MessageBox has been answered or closed).

So I was wondering if there was any way to get the same effect without it suspending the entire application, I've tried looking into Forms however I can't get it to recognise it as a thing in VisualStudios. I have also looked at GUI.Window however doesn't create a window that looks like a Windows style popup.

What do yall reckon?

(Thankyou in advance)

Answer (score 0):

In general, trying to mix Unity and WinForms is a **really bad idea**.  They were built around completely different design philosophies and if you keep going down this path, they're going to keep fighting each other.

The best option here would be to create your own lookalike windows in-game.  That would require quite a bit of work and infrastructure to set up at the beginning, but it would also give you full control over the style and behaviour of the dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Browse the asset store for assets that solve the problem for you. There are a number of dialog type assets you can grab and plug into your unity project to get you running quickly. A lot of them mimic windows features like moving around, scrolling or X to close.